# Google Places and cURL

Tags: php, curl, google-places-api

I'm new to Google Places and don't know if I set it up right.  Here is my test code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "location=45.508867,-73.554242&accuracy=500&sensor=false&key=(api key)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

But I am getting back:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I have Google Places activated in my console and got the API key from the console. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Solved.  My cURL was wrong.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location='. $latitude . ','  . $longitude .'&radius=500&name=test&sensor=false&key=(api key)');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```